# DBI Row / delegate behavior between ruby 1.8.7 and 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.8.7, ruby-2.1, ruby-1.8

I execute the following code in ruby 1.8.7 to read rows from my database:

```
require 'dbi'
db_conn_handle = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:host=localhost;database=mydb;port=3306", "root")
sth = db_conn_handle.prepare("select accounts.id, accounts.name from accounts;")
sth.execute
info = sth.to_a
puts "Info: #{info[0].class}"
info.each do |x, y|
  puts "#{x} ... #{y}"
end
```

From the output it is clear that info[0].class is DBI::Row. This code works perfectly when executed with ruby 1.8.7 (rails 3.2.17)

When I try executing it in ruby 2.1.5 / rails 3.2.17, it gives the following error:

```
/home/rjain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/delegate.rb:392:in `__getobj__': not delegated (ArgumentError)
    from /home/rjain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/delegate.rb:341:in `block in delegating_block'
    from /home/rjain/mac/query.rb:7:in `each'
    from /home/rjain/mac/query.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rjain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:52:in `eval'
    from /home/rjain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rjain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
    from /home/rjain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The file /home/rjain/mac/query.rb is pasted above. I want to understand whats the difference between ruby 2.1 and 1.8 that causes this issue. What is the fix for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same issue, tracked down the problem.

Find lib/dbi/row.rb in the gem directory. Line 212 or thereabouts should read

```
        if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/
```

Edit it to be

```
        if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/ || RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2/
```

Comment: Is there any work by anyone to fork dbi to incorporate this change?

Comment: Looks like no, it's not even on github any more, but I did find: https://code.hollensbe.org/erikh-archive/ruby-dbi/src/branch/master, with a note that it's no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 2):

This too, was a problem we had with code written with Ruby 1.8x , when run in 2.1.0 it coughed up
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/delegate.rb:392:in `__getobj__': not delegated (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/delegate.rb:341:in`block in delegating_block'

Once we found jsc comment above, we altered the file row.rb in the dbi gem folder. Again, looking for the part of:

```
 if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/
```

and update it to

`if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/ || RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2/`

After that, the app ran without a problem.